# Error Expecting Member Declaration and Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Hi everyone, I'm very new to Java and Android and I've been following a Udemy course.

I was following one of the tutorials and followed the steps exactly how it was shown but for some reason my basic code is getting errors. I had to import a Kotlin Library which I have no idea what that means. I did some research onto it saying there is some sort of relation between the two.

Under my variables im receiving an error of 'Expecting Member Declaration' and 'Val cannot be reassigned' when I hover over the nextButton (at the bottom).

[image]

Can someone help advise me on what to do?

Thank you

Comment: This is a Kotlin class and you are doing a Java-style declaration. Change to this: `private val nextButton: Button? = null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In kotlin first of all you should type val which can’t be changed and var if you change variable after. Then variable name and then class

```
lateinit var button:Button
```

Check kotlin documentation first

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Kotlin** in code but used syntax like **Java**. Try to change like below:

**Option - 1:** Remove `kotlinx.android.synthetic` from `import` and use as property.

```
//import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

private lateinit var nextButton: Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton)

    nextButton.setOnClickListener { view -> 

    }
}
```

**Option - 2:** Use `kotlinx.android.synthetic` and directly access your layout id as reference.

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    //No need to declare as class variable
    nextButton.setOnClickListener { view -> 

    }
}
```

Comment: @natashaLeah, What is the problem of my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You are using JAVA code structure inside Kotlin file.
First change your code on line 10 from

`private Button nextButton;`

to

`private lateinit var nextButton: Button`

that will solve your first issue.

And `val` is an immutable declaration of variables, change it with `var`, and you are good to go.
Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hope This may Help you

```
 private lateinit var nextButton: Button
 nextButton= findViewById(R.id.nextButton) as Button;
```